# How to include page from one package into another?

Tags: webmethods

I am trying to create a package which will collect UIs from various WM packages into one.

I have the core site in pub folder of one package and wanted to use %include% method. 
But, if I wanted to use entire URL, it doesn't work. neither using just pathname.

Only what will allow to load the page from another package is relative path to the index.dsp of the package.

```
%include ../../../anotherPackage/pub/index.dsp%
```

Problem with this solution is that in case that the anotherPackage/pub/index.dsp contains also some includes locally from the package then they are not loaded because the "cursor" is still pointing to the master package from which I have the anotherPackage/pub/index.dsp included.

Anyone fought with same problem? 
Exists there any other way than  how to solve it?

Thanks, Reddy

Comment: And did you tried full path instead of relative? Like `/package/index.dsp` ? (Not sure if this is what you meant by "entire URL"). Maybe another option are frames...

Comment: Hello, yes, I did. But the include really works only with linux relative path.